# find symmetric line of given two line

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

I have one question. Suppose that we have two lines given by equations

> $$y=2x+3$$
>   $$y=-2x+11$$

I want to find  all equations of lines which these two given lines have same distances from them in plane.As I know symmetric means that the distance between it and the two given lines must be equal. So suppose  that  the requested line is $$y=kx+b$$

after  calculating distances I found the following equation
$2k-7b=0$    what does it mean? May you help me?

Comment: This is discussed in the general case at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38665/equation-of-angle-bisector-given-the-equations-of-two-lines-in-2d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we say something in a plane is symmetric about a line, we mean it's reflection over that line is unchanged. So this is misleading. How do you define the distance between two lines? The angle? If so, you are looking for an angular bisector of the two lines. But there are two, the vertical line and horizontal line passing through the intersection point of those two lines. The coordinates of this intersection point are calculated as follows:

$$2x+3-y=0, -2x+11-y=0$$
$$\implies 0=(2x+3-y)-(-2x+11-y)=4x-8$$
$$\implies x=2, \implies 2x+3-y=7-y=0 \implies y=7.$$

Thus, the vertical line is given by the graph of x=2, the horizontal by the graph of y=7.

In general, you would take this intersection point and find the lines passing through it whose angle at the intersection is one of the two which are halfway between those of the two lines you started from. Since the slopes $m, s$ of your starting lines are the tangent of these two angles, one of your angles is given by the average of the arctangents of those two slopes, $\frac{arctan(m)+arctan(s)}{2}$, and the other is that angle plus $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence the slopes of your solution lines are $tan(\frac{arctan(m)+arctan(s)}{2}), tan(\frac{arctan(m)+arctan(s)+\pi}{2})$.

Comment: so it means that   slope  of unknown line  is  one half  one of their  slope?

Comment: @dato It does not. Your first two slopes were $-2, 2$, so the first new slope is $\frac{-2+2}{2}=0.$ I should have said "slopes halfway between *those* of the two lines you started from."

Comment: but second slope is $1/0$ it can't be right?

Comment: @dato The first line's slope is 0, which means a line orthogonal to it is vertical, or of infinite slope. For example, try converting your equations into functions of $y$ and applying this method!

Comment: In your text you have suggested taking the average of the slopes $m$ to get the bisector. It is not as simple as that because the slope $m$ is the tangent of the angle with the axis, and it is the angles you need to average not their tangents. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38665/equation-of-angle-bisector-given-the-equations-of-two-lines-in-2d

Comment: @MarkBennet Ack, you're right. It would be so much easier, though. Still, if the slopes are negatives of eachother the bisectors will still be horizontal and vertical, so that's useful to check first.

Comment: Indeed - the context of this question was unclear, but solving it did not need the full machinery.

Comment: Also, if $a$ is the first solution's slope, the second's slope is still $-\frac{1}{a}$, so it's not necessary to compute two separate tangents.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you calculated, but for reference, the two lines you are looking for (the angular bisectors) are given by $y=7$ and by $x=2$.

Comment: so does it means that my method is correct?