# Write the equation of a line that contains $(0,0)$ and is the angle bisector of two lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Two lines are given: $3x-y-4=0$ and $2x+6y+3=0$. The problem requires to find the equation of the angle bisector which contains the point $M(0,0)$.

Here are my attempts: I first try to find the angle between the two given lines. Then I find the half of the angle. Then i use that half angle in order to find the coefficient k for the required line. But I still do not receive the correct answer.

I will appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first answer in this question should explain how the equation is derived: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38665/equation-of-angle-bisector-given-the-equations-of-two-lines-in-2d?rq=1. Once you get the angle bisectors, then you can find out which one passes through $(0.0)$.

Comment: You mean "The problem requires to find the equation of the bisector of the angle which contains the point M(0,0)", don't you?