# Find angle of rotation of hyperbola given two asymptotes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Given two asymptotes $y=m_1x+b_1$ and $y=m_2x+b_2$, and a point on hyperbola $(p,q)$ is there a formula for finging an angle of rotation?

I've found a formula ([How do I find the slope of an angle bisector, given the equations of the two lines that form the angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084774/how-do-i-find-the-slope-of-an-angle-bisector-given-the-equations-of-the-two-lin)) for finding two possible lines that contain the major axis, but I don't how to use the point to find unique line.

Comment: What angle do you have in mind? Isn't that the slope of the asymptote?

Comment: The axes of the hyperbola are the bisectors of the angles between the asymptotes.

Comment: Thank you. I've found it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084774/how-do-i-find-the-slope-of-an-angle-bisector-given-the-equations-of-the-two-lin

Comment: Point $(p,q)$ lies in one of the four angles formed by the asymptotes: choose as major axis the bisector lying in the same angle.

Comment: In practice, the sign you must choose in that formula is the same as the sign of $${m_1p-q+b_1\over m_2p-q+b_2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I just need to take a point on a bisector and check whether it has lies in the same (or opposite) quadrant as the given point.